# Como puedo reemplazar las "x" de un string por numeros aleatorios

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de reemplazar las **x** de un `string` por números aleatorios del *0* al *9* pero mi `string` contiene varias **x** y me reemplaza todas las **x** por el mismo numero. Lo que busco es lograr que me reemplace las **x** pero que no todas sean iguales.

```
<?php

$lista = '12345xxxxx';

$num = str_replace("x", rand(0,9), $lista);

echo $num;

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu lógica esta bien el problema es que la función `str_replace` sirve para remplazar todas las coincidencias que le pasas por parámetros por el segundo parámetro y este resultado no es lo que estas buscando, la cuestion esta en que tu debes de pasar tu string primero y después seccionarlo para que de esta forma remplazas las x una por una en lugar de todas a la vez. La solución que te sugiero es la siguiente:

```
$lista = '12345xxxxx';

for ($i=0; $i < strlen($lista); $i++) { 
    if ($lista[$i] == 'x') {
        $lista[$i] = rand(0,9);
    }
}

echo $lista;
```

En esta solución como puedes ver tienes que pasar tu `$lista` por un ciclo para que de esta forma logres pasar una x a la vez y al mismo tiempo iras remplazando por un valor random que ira cambiando con cada iteración en el ciclo.